# How do I correctly calculate the S-parameters of cascaded lines?

Tags: analog, transmission-line, s-parameters

Suppose I have two coupled transmission lines cascaded. I know the S parameters of both lines. From these S parameters, I can extra SA and SB

S = [SA SB; SB SA]

Now, I can find S_odd = SA-SB and S_even = SA+SB

I can convert S_odd and S_even to ABCD_odd and ABCD_even. All these steps are for each of the 2 lines separately.

Now, I want to get the overall S parameters

Can I do the following? -

1. Multiply ABCD_odd_1 and ABCD_odd_2 to get ABCD_odd_eq and similarly ABCD_even_eq
2. Convert these to S_odd_eq and S_even_eq
3. Convert to full S_eq

Diagram:

[image: Cascaded Coupled Lines]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A diagram wouldn't hurt. I'm not sure what you mean by 'two coupled transmission lines cascaded'.

Comment: Hi. I added a diagram. Hopefully it will make the question more clear